# CANNOT POST/ ERROR NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to back-end developing .. I am facing a problem here :

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Campground = require("./models/campground");
var Comment = require("./models/comment");
var seedDB = require("./seeds");


mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp", {
  useMongoClient: true
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: false
}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

seedDB();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("landing");
});
app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res) {
  Campground.find({}, function(err, allCampgrounds) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR!!");
    } else {
      res.render("campgrounds/campgrounds", {
        campgrounds: allCampgrounds
      });
    }
  });
});
app.post("/campgrounds", function(req, res) {
  // get info from form;
  var name = req.body.name;
  var image = req.body.image;
  var description = req.body.description;
  var newCampground = {
    name: name,
    image: image,
    description: description
  };
  Campground.create(newCampground)
  res.redirect("/campgrounds");
});

app.get("/campgrounds/new", function(req, res) {
  res.render("campgrounds/new");
});

app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res) {
  Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground) {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    } else {
      res.render("campgrounds/info", {
        campground: foundCampground
      });
    }
  });
});

app.get("/campgrounds/:id/comments/new", function(req, res) {
  Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err");
    } else {
      res.render("comments/new", {
        campground: campground
      });
    }
  });
});


app.post("/campground/:id/comments", function(req, res) {
  Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error!!!");
      res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    } else {
      Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment) {

        if (err) {
          console.log("error!!!!!")
        } else {
          campground.comments.push(comment);
          campground.save();
         res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
       }
     });
   }
  });
});

app.listen("3000", function() {
  console.log("THE YELPCAMP SERVER HAS STARTED!!!");
});
```

**seeds.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Campground = require("./models/campground");
var Comment = require("./models/comment");
var data = [
  {
    name: "Cloud",
    image:"http://www.itworldcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cp1_0111.jpg",
    description:"very beautiful!!"
  },
  {
    name: "Dessert Rose",
    image:"http://glennbates.com/desertrose/images/Desert-Rose-Plant-Care.jpg",
    description:"very beautiful!!"
  },
  {
    name: "SKY!",
    image:"http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/1754/1-jpg.jpg",
    description:"very beautiful!!"
  }
]


function seedDB(){
  Campground.remove({}, function(err){
  if(err){
  console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Campground Deleted!!");
   data.forEach(function(seed){
    Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground){
      if(err){console.log("error!!");}
      else {
           console.log("Added A Campground");
           //ADD COMMENT!!
           Comment.create({
             text: "This Place is great , but There was no internet",
             author: "Obada"
           }, function(err, comment){
             if(err){console.log(err)}
             else {             
                   campground.comments.push(comment);
                   campground.save();
                   console.log("Created a comment");
                  }
           });
           }
    });
  }); 

});


}
module.exports = seedDB;
```

**/models/comment.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var commentSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: String
});



module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

**/models/campground.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var campgroundsSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  image: String,
  description: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment"
    }
  ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundsSchema);
```

When I run it on port 3000 it gives me "Cannot POST /campgrounds/(id)"
P.S : I am using codeanywhere .

Comment: Check your route `campgrounds` and `campground`.

Comment: There is no post route for this `campgrounds/(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define necessary route. Add this

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res) {
 Campground.create(req.body, function (err, small) {
     if (err) console.log(err);

     res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + small._id);
   })
}):
```

Comment: What would I write inside it ?

Comment: Ok .. after adding it .. and running it , it printed out {"a":1}

Comment: Yes, it renders JSON, response. If your want to render HTML page, then use res.render('campgrounds'). But make sure that you have campgrounds.ejs view. Hope I answered your question

Comment: Thank You very much for your help .. but I want it to go back to /campground/:id and show the added comment

Comment: IT WORKS !! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

In Comments dir, new.ejs file, you may have missed /comments -----

```
<form action="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments" method="post">
```